# Facebook avatars are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, facebook

What happened to Stack Overflow profile pictures connected by Facebook?

Did Facebook change their way of sharing public API / Data?

[image: Profile picture from Facebook is just an empty silloute]

Comment: Reported on MSO as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366259/my-profile-picture-disappeared

Comment: See [this related question on Stack Overflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917726/retrieving-default-image-all-url-profile-picture-from-facebook-graph-api), and [this thread on Facebook's developer forums](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/) (can't verify since I deleted my account), which confirm that something has changed. They're saying it's a bug, but this does seem in line with Facebook's recent policy and API changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your picture is back. The pictures of other users that had the same problem are back too. So, this is solved.

The problem happened because your picture came from facebook and there was a problem in the facebook - Stack Overflow integration, since facebook is doing some changes in their APIs to reinforce security.